# Prevent Redis values from being recalculated by many clients at once

Tags: php, mysql, redis

Suppose we have some important counters on all our pages and our website is heavily loaded. We store them in a set of Redis keys which automatically EXPIRE in an hour, or so.

In our code, we check if a key containing a counter is present, and, if not, we execute some heavy operation (let's say it's a COUNT(*) with multiple WHEREs in MySQL) to recalculate its value, then we set the key's value with our newly recalculated one.

```
<?php
  $counter = $redis->get('My:Heavy_Counter');
  if ($counter === null) {
    $counter = $counter->recalculate();
    $redis->set('My:Heavy_Counter', $counter);
  }
?>
```

The problem is each webpage client is going to do the above operation.

Is there an elegant way to recalculate those keys  with just the first client's request while leaving the other thousands of clients to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement simple locking system using Redis `SET` command:

From `SET` command [description](http://redis.io/commands/set):

> The command `SET resource-name anystring NX EX max-lock-time` is a
>   simple way to implement a locking system with Redis.
>
> A client can acquire the lock if the above command returns `OK` (or
>   retry after some time if the command returns `Nil`), and remove the lock
>   just using `DEL`.
>
> The lock will be auto-released after the expire time is reached.